# BO webi report custom scheduling run using custom filter value time

Tags: reporting-services, business-intelligence, business-objects

These are Webi, user created reports.
Is it possible to schedule a Webi report based on another input, i.e. expose a time in which a process was finished (this can be obtained via a SQL call, service call, etc). The issue is that if a user schedules a report for 9PM but a process to move data, etc has not completed then that forces the user to keep re-freshing the report hoping that the process has been complete.

Ideally, in the selection UI add to the dropdown for 'when' the option 'Use Process X completion Time' (since it is a daily report). Then starting around 9PM check to see if that 'time" value is populated then refresh (run) the report. Or it could just be a flag that the process has finished.

User's in the webi environment are asking for this, and moving their reprots to BO is not an option. That's why they have the custom webi enviroment.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you caching reports?

Comment: I don't believe so, but why would caching have anything to do with refreshing reports? The issue is that if a user runs one of their reports yet a process that affects that daily data has not completed then that report is not as accurate as it could be. Then the user has to re-run (refresh) it again just to make sure even though they scheduled it.

Comment: It is like a report with a scehduled time but has a dependecy on a process. Then after that process is complete, then run their report.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what version of Webi you're using but if it's XI3.1 then I would use an Event to trigger the report refresh.  You'll have to create the Event in the CMC and then add it to the schedule for the report (Events to wait for:).

The Event can be based on a text file.  I've had our ETL process create a text file when our load is complete and then setup a Windows task to create various text files that are used as Events in the CMC to trigger groups of report refreshes.

Also, the report has to be waiting for the Event before it occurs and then once the Event occurs the report refreshes.  For example, I have set all the reports that are triggered to start at 1 am and end at 9 am.  The Windows Scheduled Task to create the text files mentioned previously does not start until 1:01 am.  So the reports starting looking for the text file (which doesn't exist) at 1 am then sees the file at 1:01 am then starts the report refresh.

You must have a Windows Scheduled Task to delete the trigger files before your next desired refresh.  In my case, the reports are refreshed daily and the files are deleted at 6 pm.